# jQueryUI Tabs into mobile menu

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQueryUITabs , and i converted it into a mobile menu. I have been trying without success to close the mobile menu when i click on a tab , i've tried adding a new class to the menu to display none and display block , but its buggy so i'm looking for some help on how i can close the tab group once you select a tab and show its content.

I set up a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ju6q9L4a/30/

I'm not any good at jquery so just pretty much used the wiget and made a call to execute the tabs to work.

```
   $( ".jquery-tabs" ).tabs();
```

I added this to show and hide the menu , but its not working very fluid

```
$( ".site-navigation li" ).click(function() {
  $('.site-navigation').hide();
});
$( "#nav-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $('.site-navigation').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding the data-toggle and target to the li themselves

```
<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-1"><a href='#tab-1'>Tab #1</a></li>
<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-1"><a href='#tab-2'>Tab #2</a></li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ju6q9L4a/41/